How do I use React Router to show a completely separate page?
I am creating a single-page front-end project with React, the thing is that I would like to create a page-like component that should be rendered individually.
The Concept is basically:
Page-1: Home Page
The Main page with its components/sections
Page-2: About Us Page
The second page i intend to create and should be rendered individually
But when i click the About Us item in my navbar, it doensn´t redirect to the about page, instead it just renderizes the component between my Header and my Services component
FILE:APP.JS
// css
import './App.css';

// script
import './assets/js/script';

// components
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Newsletter from './components/Newsletter/Newsletter';
import Services from './components/Services/Services';
import Work from './components/Work/Work';
import WorkProcess from './components/WorkProcess/WorkProcess';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Testimonials from './components/Testimonials/Testimonials';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import AboutPage from './components/AboutPage/AboutPage';

// routes
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Header />
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
       </Routes>  
       <Services />
       <Work />
       <WorkProcess />
       <Newsletter />
       <About />
       <Testimonials />
       <Contact />
       <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

FILE:Navbar.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Navbar = () => {
    const [navToggler, setNavToggler] = useState(false);
    const closeNavbar = () => setNavToggler(false);
    const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(0);
    
    const handleScroll = () => {
        setScrollPos(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    };

    useEffect (() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: "smooth",
        })
    }
    const scrollToSection = (id) => {
        const section = document.getElementById(id);
        section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
      };
    
  return (
    <nav className={scrollPos > 100 ? 'navbar scrolled' : 'navbar'}>
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='navbar-content'>
                <div className='brand-and-toggler flex flex-sb'>
                    <Link to = "/" className='navbar-brand text-uppercase fw-7 text-white ls-2 fs-22' onClick={scrollToTop}>Ophidium</Link>
                    <button type = "button" className='navbar-open-btn text-white' onClick={() => setNavToggler(!navToggler)}>
                        <FaBars size = {30}/>
                    </button>

                    <div className={navToggler ? "navbar-collapse show-navbar-collapse" : "navbar-collapse"}>
                        <button type = "button" className='navbar-close-btn text-white' onClick={closeNavbar}>
                            <FaTimes size = {30}/>
                        </button>
                        <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to="/" className='nav-link text-white ls-1 text-uppercase fw-6 fs-22' onClick={() => scrollToSection('home')}>Home</Link>
                        </li>
                                <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to="/services" className='nav-link text-white ls-1 text-uppercase fw-6 fs-22' onClick={() => scrollToSection('services')}>Services</Link>
                                </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to="#workprocess" className='nav-link text-white ls-1 text-uppercase fw-6 fs-22' onClick={() => scrollToSection('workprocess')}>Work Process</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                                <Link to = "/about" className='nav-link text-white ls-1 text-uppercase fw-6 fs-22'>About Us</Link>
                            </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to="#socialmedia" className='nav-link text-white ls-1 text-uppercase fw-6 fs-22' onClick={() => scrollToSection('socialmedia')}>Social Media</Link>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar

FILE:AboutPage.jsx
import React from 'react'

const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  )
};

export default AboutPage

PROJECT PRINT:Main Page
(https://i.sstatic.net/TMBhhXyJ.png)
AFTER CLICKING ABOUT US
(https://i.sstatic.net/65cpdPwB.png)
Already tried to route, expected the component to be rendered individually but insted it just pops up in the main page.

You have the route defined between the header and the services, it's normal that when you navigate to /about it renders <AboutPage />

React Router is kind of like a fancy switch statement for conditionally rendering components based on URIs. It lets you simplify the creation of pages, by having things like headers, navigation, footers, etc. be reused, and only the main contents, like the main page info or about page info, to change. It makes those "inner" components simpler by not needing to care about the other components, or copy those other components in a bunch of places.
If you want a completely different page when navigating to /about, then the Router components must be higher up in the app component tree, and wrap the entire page of components, like:

function AboutPage() { ... }

function Main() {
   return (
      <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Header />
       <Services />
       <Work />
       <WorkProcess />
       <Newsletter />
       <About />
       <Testimonials />
       <Contact />
       <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
   )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
         <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
       </Routes>  
    </div>
  );
}

